# Integer.valueOf() cannot find symbol in Iterator

Tags: java, generics, iterator, integer

Hi I want to write my own `Iterator` over a linked list (which returns the values in the list). For some reason I get a "cannot find symbol" error when calling `Integer.valueOf()`

```
import java.util.*;
class List {
    private Node head;
    private class IntIterator<Integer> implements Iterator<Integer>{
        private Node currentNode;

    private IntIterator(){
        currentNode = head;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return currentNode != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next(){
        if (!hasNext()) {
            return Integer.valueOf(-1); //the compiler doesnt like this..
        }
        int val = currentNode.val;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        return Integer.valueOf(val); //and that!
    }

    public IntIterator<Integer> iterator(){
        return new IntIterator<Integer>();
    }
}
```

I don't know how this issue can happen since the compiler doesn't complain about `Integer` in the other parts of the program.

Anyway I hope you can help me with that issue!

Comment: @Lee Compilation errors don't have stack traces. Please moderate your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that type parameter `Integer` hides visible type `java.lang.Integer`. You should write like

```
private class IntIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
```

instead of

```
private class IntIterator<Integer> implements Iterator<Integer>
                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems you don't understand generics completely. I suggest you to read about [them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/).

Comment: Ok I understand now. Does the use of the Iterator in my case add unnecessary performance overhead?

Comment: @user3025417, in my view, you don't need to check `hasNext` in `next` (your API user has to do it)

Comment: @user3025417, you could consider `private class Itr` in `ArrayList`, it  provides good approach